# How to test the value of a mock call in python is within a range of possible values

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

Is there a way to test the value sent to a mocked call for `time.sleep`?  The following is not working as expected.

```py
# tmp.py

import time

from random import randint
from unittest import mock
from unittest import TestCase

def retry_delay(tries, delay):
    delay = int(delay)  # ensure it's compatible with randint
    cap = 600  # 10 minutes
    if cap < delay:
        cap = delay
    exp_delay = int(delay + pow(tries, 2))
    pause = randint(delay, min(cap, exp_delay))
    time.sleep(pause)


class TestDelay(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        pass

    @mock.patch('time.sleep')
    def test_retry_delay(self, mock_sleep):
        delay_time = 10  # something less than the default max of 600
        retry_delay(1, delay_time)
        assert mock_sleep.call_count == 1
        sleep_call = mock_sleep.call_args
        assert mock.call(delay_time) <= sleep_call
```

Dropping into `--pdb` in the unit tests indicates that `mock.call` supports inequalities, e.g.

```py
$ nosetests --pdb tmp.py
(Pdb) mock.call(10) <= mock.call(10)
True
(Pdb) mock.call(10) <= mock.call(8)
False

(Pdb) sleep_call
call(10)
(Pdb) type(sleep_call)
<class 'mock.mock._Call'>
(Pdb) mock.call(10)
call(10)
(Pdb) type(mock.call(10))
<class 'mock.mock._Call'>
(Pdb) mock.call(10) <= sleep_call
*** TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'tuple'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access the call args directly:

```
>>> mock.call(10).args
(10,)
```

Example:

```
>>> mock.call(10).args <= mock.call(11).args
True
>>> mock.call(10).args <= mock.call(9).args
False
```

Comment: In a pdb-session, the mock is not behaving this way, e.g.
`mock_sleep.mock_calls[0] -> call(279.3204104677561)` but
`mock_sleep.mock_calls[0].args -> args` and not `279.32`; maybe this is just pdb?